# Bugs with mplstereonet and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The problem is with the package MPLSTEREONET installable with pip.

With matplotlib version 3.4 or less the package works well. With matplotlib 3.5 and above someone could get the message of error described above.

I have installed mplstereonet under pythpn 3.11.4 and maptplotlib 3.7.2.
in the link https://mplstereonet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/index.html I have tried the script "equal_area_equal_angle_comparison.py"

I got the following TypeError message:

```
python equal_area_equal_angle_comparison.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khairi/Documents/TUT_MPLSTEREONET/equal_area_equal_angle_comparison.py", line 18, in <module>
    ax.set_azimuth_ticklabels([])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/FPSolution/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mplstereonet/stereonet_axes.py", line 341, in set_azimuth_ticklabels
    return self._polar.set_xticklabels(labels, fontdict, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/FPSolution/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return get_method(self)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/FPSolution/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 297, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Axis.set_ticklabels() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The problem, I guess could be with matplotlib package.